# I want to Display local Images in Image Picker Controller from my project folder.

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new in  objective c.where i need to display the images in a grid form in Image Picker Controller from my project.
where i have many images, when the images will display i will click on one of them and it will display on another screen in  Image View.
i need your help with source code thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There's a lot of examples if you search for it...

Example,

Apple Developers

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html

Another one

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-camera-iphone-app/

I.